# Squid as a proxy for a specific site?

Tags: squid

I'm new to Squid, and am investigating whether it would be able to accomplish a task at hand.

I need to "transpose" port 80 of a static IP to the port 1088 on a dynamic IP that has a hostname pointer though no-ip.com.  In other words:

- somedomain.com has an A record 1.2.3.4
- someotherdomain.com a dynamic A record (updated via no-ip.com)
- the static IP 1.2.3.4 is served by a proxy (such as Squid?) at port 80 which, when accessed (http://www.somedomain.com), relays the request to someotherdomain.com:1088 and displays it as if it came from 1.2.3.4 (somedomain.com).
- somedomain.com cannot be used as a general proxy to access other locations than someotherdomain.com; in fact, the relay in the back-end should be transparent to the user accessing somedomain.com

Thanks for any insights on this!

Ville

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a reverse proxy and yes, [Squid can do that](http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/ReverseProxy).

```
http_port 1.2.3.4:80 accel defaultsite=www.somedomain.com
cache_peer someotherdomain.com parent 1088 0 no-query originserver
```

Apache can as well with mod_proxy:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
ServerName www.somedomain.com
DocumentRoot c:/docroot

ProxyPass / http://someotherdomain.com:1088/
ProxyPassReverse / http://someotherdomain.com:1088/
</VirtualHost>
```